# name 'listdir' is not defined

Tags: python, operating-system, python-os, listdir

I have been trying to run this cell on google colab but every time it says 'listdir' is not defined. I have imported 'os' in the previous cell before running this cell. Can anyone please help to find the error here?

```
images =  [(train_image_dir+f) for f in listdir(train_image_dir) if isfile(join(train_image_dir, f))]
```

Comment: mate, either import os.listdir, then call it ass listdir or import os then os.listdir

Comment: Importing a module does not automatically make all of its functions directly visible.  You still have to refer to it with its module name: `os.listdir()`

Comment: Please format the code properly, it is very unreadable

Comment: Or you could `from os import *` but that's a good way to pollute your namespace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of calling `listdir()`, call `os.listdir()`. A bit unclear what you're trying to accomplish from your indentation but you need to indicate the package from which all of these functions are from, unless you specifically import each function. As state above by @E.Serra, either of these options will work:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import join, isfile
```

or:

```
import os

# later in code...
os.listdir(directory)
os.path.join("string1", "string2")
os.isfile(file)
```