# NameError: name 'isfile' is not defined

Tags: python

I am trying to create a dataset with all the datasets stored in a folder.
I have used the code below with any issues yesterday, but not it seems not working:

```
> **> Error:**
> ---> 35 data = create_dataframe(paths)
> 
> <ipython-input-21-b5315aeab0d7> in create_dataframe(paths)
>      15     dataframes = {
>      16         (path, file): pd.read_csv(path + file + '.csv')
> ---> 17         for path in paths
>      18         for file in get_files_in_path(path)
>      19     }
> 
> <ipython-input-21-b5315aeab0d7> in <dictcomp>(.0)
>      16         (path, file): pd.read_csv(path + file + '.csv')
>      17         for path in paths
> ---> 18         for file in get_files_in_path(path)
>      19     }
>      20 
> 
> <ipython-input-21-b5315aeab0d7> in get_files_in_path(path)
>      11 
>      12     def get_files_in_path(path):
> ---> 13         return [f.split('.')[0] for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]
>      14 
>      15     dataframes = {
> 
> <ipython-input-21-b5315aeab0d7> in <listcomp>(.0)
>      11 
>      12     def get_files_in_path(path):
> ---> 13         return [f.split('.')[0] for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]
>      14 
>      15     dataframes = {
> 
> **NameError: name 'isfile' is not defined**
```

Could you please tell me how to fix it?

**Code:**

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import join
import os

def create_dataframe(paths):

    def get_files_in_path(path):
        return [f.split('.')[0] for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]

    dataframes = {
        (path, file): pd.read_csv(path + file + '.csv')
        for path in paths
        for file in get_files_in_path(path)
    }

    df = pd.concat(dataframes, names=['path', 'file', '_'])    

    return df
```

Following this question and answer, [name 'listdir' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62286478/name-listdir-is-not-defined), I have also tried to change `os.listdir`, `os.path`, `os.isfile`, `os.path.join` but nothing has changed.

Comment: Haven't actually tested this, but you may need to also import `isfile` like you do for `join`

Comment: Use `os.path.isfile()` instead of 'isfile'

Comment: isfile is clearly not defined, make sure you import it correctly to use it

Comment: Thank you so much to all of you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`import os.path` does not import every name defined in the `os.path` module into the current namespace; it only imports the name `os`. You still need to use the qualified name `os.path.isfile`, unless you use `from os.path import isfile`.

Answer (score -1):

make `from os.path import join` as `from os.path import join, isfile`.